# FasterXML: Could not deserialize form XML to POJO

Tags: java, xml, fasterxml

I'm trying to deserialize XML.

```
<server>
    <url>localhost</url>
    <port>8080</port>
</server>
```

to POJO

```
class Storage {
    private Server server;
}

class Server {
    private String url;
    private Integer port;
}
```

Here is my fire code

```
resources = new FileInputStream("/resources/config/" + file);
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
storage = mapper.readValue(resources, Storage.class);
```

But it doesn't work.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
```

I tried to add JAX-B annotation to Storage and Server class, but the same error occurred.

*UPD*

When I add `mapper = new XmlMapper();` that I recieve `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "url"`

Comment: You'll very much need those annotations, but also a XML mapper, not `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: It seems like `ObjectMapper` expects JSON here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `ObjectMapper` instances are meant to deserialize JSON. So you won't be able to use it as is. Use a `XmlMapper`.

Second, the root of your XML, `<server>`, contains two elements, `<url>` and `<port>`. But your root Java type, `Storage`,

```
storage = mapper.readValue(resources, Storage.class);
```

contains only one, `server`. So you need a wrapper element to act as root in the XML

```
<Storage>
    <server>
        <url>localhost</url>
        <port>8080</port>
    </server>
</Storage>
```

Also, I'm assuming you meant for

```
private Server url;
```

to be

```
private String url;
```